# Generating a symbol with content: CSS

Tags: jquery, css

I am using [this](http://selfthinker.github.io/CSS-Playing-Cards/#options) markup to generate some playing cards within a blackjack game Im creating using JavaScript.

The CSS for each card is generated using jQuery, all fine apart from the content:after tag. The example for the front of a card looks like so

```
<div class="card rank-7 spades">
  <span class="rank">7</span>
  <span class="suit">&spades;</span>
</div>
```

The &spades generates the spades symbol (♠) on the card, so Im trying to pass it through using jQuery like so

```
 var name = $(this).attr('data-card-name'); // data-card-name = spades in this example
 $(this).children('.suit').text('&'+name+';');
```

but it literally treats it as a string and does not generate the symbol, how can i pass it through so it generates the symbol?

Thanks

Comment: Well, that's what `text` means ;-)

Comment: yeah my bad....simple really :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use html() instead of text():

```
$(this).children('.suit').html('&'+name+';');
```

Or use like this:

```
$(this).children('.suit').text('&'+name+';').html();
```